# GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method())

Tags: c#, msbuild

I am trying to get some net core 2.1 projects to build on a new build server that we have. We have installed Visual studio tools for 2017 and 2019.

I am getting this error when it tried to build it via our TFS build process. We use cake scripts to build the code.

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.TargetFrameworkInference.targets(54,5): error MSB4186: Invalid static method invocation syntax: "[MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')". [MSBuild]::GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method()), e.g. $([System.IO.Path]::Combine(`a`, `b`)).  [D:\Agents\EROS-006\_work\2\s\src\Cases.CommandHandlers\Cases.CommandHandlers.csproj]
```

Is it something to do with the csproj contents? We have this declared at the top as this bit of the message stands out

```
GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier Static method invocation should be of the form: $([FullTypeName]::Method())
```

The csproj version details:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>2.1.4</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
    <TargetLatestAspNetCoreRuntimePatch>True</TargetLatestAspNetCoreRuntimePatch>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

I have searched for an answer but seem to point to mono related things, which we don't use at all, its a windows machine with the visual studio tools installed as mentioned above.

The cake build part looks like this

```
Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("Version")
    .Does(() =>
    {
     var settings = new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings()
     {
         Sources = packageSources
     };

     DotNetCoreRestore(settings);

        if(useLatestMsBuild){
        MSBuild(solution, new MSBuildSettings {
            Configuration = configuration,
            MaxCpuCount = maxcpucount,
            ArgumentCustomization = args => args
                .Append("/p:Version=" + versionInfo.InformationalVersion.Replace("/", "-"))
                .Append("/p:AssemblyVersion=" + versionInfo.AssemblySemVer)
                .Append("/p:FileVersion=" + versionInfo.AssemblySemVer)
        });
        }else{
        MSBuild(solution, new MSBuildSettings {
            Configuration = configuration,
            MaxCpuCount = maxcpucount,
            ToolVersion = MSBuildToolVersion.VS2017,
            Restore = true,
            ArgumentCustomization = args => args
                .Append("/p:Version=" + versionInfo.InformationalVersion.Replace("/", "-"))
                .Append("/p:AssemblyVersion=" + versionInfo.AssemblySemVer)
                .Append("/p:FileVersion=" + versionInfo.AssemblySemVer)
        });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Make sure that the MSBuild.exe version you are using is 16.7 or higher.  The `GetTargetFrameworkIdentifier` property function is not available in earlier versions ([see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022)).

Comment: Has the build agent been restarted since the Visual Studio build tools were installed?

Comment: I did pass in useLatestMsBuild=true and that did start using the latest MSBuild 17, but still the same error. I also restarted the box after the updating of the build tools. thanks

Comment: Well, I just noticed that you are using cake. Are you sure (I'm not, no expert) that it is really picking up the correct / desired MSBuild version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at further build steps in cake and powershell there was mention of it compiling with mono instead of the default. Updating cake to version 2.0 and rewiting it from the ground up seems to resolve the issue.

Installing **Visual Studio Build Tools 2022** and latest **nuget.exe** added to the environmental variable PATH seemed to help. Ideally installing everything that the build server has on it and running the same scripts locally helped a lot.